# How to Integrate Web form with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to integrate new contact form with wordpress for public display/data entry like in this drupal page [image: drupal web form]

I want to have this

[image: form to be used as public]

To be a web form for data entry, showing with the wordpress.

Comment: i removed the webform-civicrm tag as that is Drupal specific

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the Drupal page you screenshot is a Profile as you can see in the URL. To find out how to display a Profile as a public form on a WordPress site I recommend you refer to this [Chapter](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/profiles/) and read the section called "Standalone forms with Profiles"